# How to get the max/min value in Pandas DataFrame when nan value in it

Tags: python, pandas

Since one column of my pandas dataframe has `nan` value, so when I want to get the max value of that column, it just return error.

```
>>> df.iloc[:, 1].max()
'error:512'
```

How can I skip that `nan` value and get the max value of that column?

Comment: Please post the DataFrame. The max function skips `nan` by default - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html).

Comment: What is "error 512"? Is that something written by you? python/pandas does not throw that error AFAIK.

Comment: @Merlin, 'error:512' is returned by the python console.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `NumPy`'s help with [`np.nanmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html), [`np.nanmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html) :

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
   A   B  C
0  7 NaN  8
1  3   3  5
2  8   1  7
3  3   0  3
4  8   2  7

In [29]: np.nanmax(df.iloc[:, 1].values)
Out[29]: 3.0

In [30]: np.nanmin(df.iloc[:, 1].values)
Out[30]: 0.0
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use [Series.dropna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html).

```
res = df.iloc[:, 1].dropna().max()
```

Comment: This is quite nice. np.nanmin and np.nanmax are sensitive to warnings as discussed [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9008), but this approach solves that issue.

Answer (score 4):

if you dont use iloc or loc, it is simple as:

```
df['column'].max()
```

or

```
df['column'][df.index.min():df.index.max()]
```

or any kind of range in this second square brackets

Answer (score 4):

You can set `numeric_only = True` when calling `max`:

```
df.iloc[:, 1].max(numeric_only = True)
```

### Attention:

For everyone trying to use it with `pandas.series`
This is not working nevertheless it is mentioned in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html#pandas.Series.max)

See post on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10480)

Answer (score 2):

Dataframe aggregate function`.agg()` will automatically ignore NaN value. 
`df.agg({'income':'max'})`

Besides, it can also be use together with `.groupby`

`df.groupby('column').agg({'income':['max','mean']})`

Answer (score 1):

When the df contains `NaN` values it reports `NaN` values, Using
    `np.nanmax(df.values)` gave the desired answer.